# Is it correct to say "I have new hair" or "I have a new haircut"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

You often wear your hair short. But now your hair has grown longer.

You have just had your hair cut short (similar to the style that you wore before).

Is it correct to say "**I have new hair**" or "**I have a new haircut**"?

Comment: "Now you are asking your son a question." What question is this? I am confused with exactly what you mean here.

Comment: You still have the _same_ hair, just less of it! (_New hair_ would suggest that your existing hair had been replaced or added to.)

Comment: I can imagine hearing **I have new hair** or **I love your new hair!** but only in reference to a hair*style*, and it's very informal and slangy.  ([Example here.](https://books.google.com/books?id=JpuGCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT26&dq=%22I+love+your+new+hair%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjclYPBx5bvAhXzdM0KHXyRCWYQ6AEwAXoECAUQAg))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your hair was long and now it's short, and that's how you normally have it, you would say

> I have had a haircut

If it is not the same as how you normally have it, you would say

> I have a new hairstyle

Comment: The problem of "I have a new hairstyle" is that. I have just 1 hairstyle. I always wear my hair short. My hair might grow longer a bit but that doesn't change my hairstyle so much. Is it still correct to say "I have a new hairstyle" after I have just got it cut shorter a bit?

Comment: Read the first sentence again!